# Throtting same saga/epic action with takeLatest on different actions

Tags: redux, redux-thunk, redux-saga, redux-observable

I'm new on redux-saga/observable stuff. But I couldn't handle my scenario which looks so fit on these. So; I want to call API if any changes happen on the form. But I don't want to call API a lot because of the performance reasons.

Basically, when I trigger SLIDERCHANGED, TEXTBOXCHANGED, CHECKBOXCHECKED, I want to call also getData function. But I need to put a delay to check other actions. For example; If SLIDERCHANGED is triggered, It should wait for 1sn and if TEXTBOXCHANGED is triggered at that time, It will be canceled and wait for 1sn more to call the getData function. So that's why I tried to implement Redux-saga or redux-observable.

I have actions types;

```
const SLIDERCHANGED = 'APP/sliderchanged';
const TEXTBOXCHANGED = 'APP/textboxchanged';
const CHECKBOXCHECKED = 'APP/checkboxchecked';
const LOADING = 'APP/loading';
const LOADDATA = 'APP/loaddata';
const ERRORLOADDATA = 'APP/errorloaddata';
```

I have also actions;

```
export function updateSliderValue(val) {
  return { type: SLIDERCHANGED, val };
}

export function updateTextboxValue(val) {
  return { type: TEXTBOXCHANGED, val };
}

export function updateCheckboxValue(val) {
  return { type: CHECKBOXCHECKED, val };
}

export function loading() {
  return { type: LOADING };
}

export function loadData(data) {
  return { type: LOADDATA, data };
}

export function errorLoadData(err) {
  return { type: ERRORLOADDATA, err };
}

export function getData(vehicleInfo) { // redux-thunk ASYNC function
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(loading());

      return dispatch(apiCall('/getAllData', {}))
        .then(payload => {
          dispatch(loaddata(payload));
        })
        .catch(error => {
          dispatch(errorLoadData(error));
        });
  };
}
```

With redux-saga, I did this but it doesn't work. It calls a getData function on each change with 1sn delay.

```
import { put, throttle } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import {
  SLIDERCHANGED,
  TEXTBOXCHANGED,
  CHECKBOXCHECKED
} from './constants';
import { getData } from './actions';


function* onFormUpdate() {
  yield put(getData());
}

export function* watchFormChange() {
  yield throttle(
    10000,
    [SLIDERCHANGED, TEXTBOXCHANGED, CHECKBOXCHECKED],
    onFormUpdate
  );
}
```

With redux-observable, Also somehow I get the same error.

```
import { ofType } from 'redux-observable';
import { delay, map, debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {
  SLIDERCHANGED,
  TEXTBOXCHANGED,
  CHECKBOXCHECKED
} from './constants';
import { getData } from './actions';

export const onFormUpdate = action => {
  return action.pipe(
    ofType(SLIDERCHANGED, TEXTBOXCHANGED, CHECKBOXCHECKED),
    debounceTime(1000),
    map(() => getData())
  );
};
```

Does anyone have any idea or opinion to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Without having tested it, I think you can write a solution like this:

```
import { delay } from 'redux-saga'
import { put } from 'redux-saga/effects'

function* onFormUpdate() {
  yield delay(1000)
  yield put(getData())
}

export function* watchFormChange() {
  yield takeLatest(
    [SLIDERCHANGED, TEXTBOXCHANGED, CHECKBOXCHECKED],
    onFormUpdate,
  )
}
```

The idea here is that `takeLatest` will cancel `onFormUpdate` as soon as another one of the three actions is dispatched. So while `onFormUpdate` is in `delay` and then canceled, the next step, which is `put`, will not be called anymore.

Comment: Hmm. Honestly, I also passed the error with this way but I think there is no way to make a general function to put "delay(1000)" for every call, right?